# matching in matching space with sed, since when it is supported?

Tags: regex, sed

i saw a script on a system i have to maintain on several (old) platforms that uses this sed regexp:

```
sed 's/\([\\\x27"]\)key\1: \1value\1//'
```

the `\\\x27` is a way to escape single quotes. so the regexp in more readable form is:

`\(['"]\)key\1: \1value\1`

it matches the first gruop as either `'` or `"` and then use `\1` within the match regexp to match the similar quote. so it will match all lines:

```
"key": "value"
'key': 'value'
```

Now it is a great solution. but i'm afraid this may not be present on older sed versions.

so the question is: **how is this feature called**, and how supported/available is it?

Comment: you understand that it is the pair of escaped parens that is doing the capturing, right? i.e. `s/\(matchThis\)/\1Too/` You can have up-to 9 pairs in a sed match expression. This feature is part of the original design of sed and should be part of any `sed` version. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter yep. but never used it on the matching side, where the group parens are. wouldn't that lead to recursive matching and such?

Comment: @gcb It makes the regex non-regular, but it's not recursion: a backreference matches the exact string matched by the referenced group; it doesn't attempt to re-match the group with all its variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called "backreference" and I would say it's a standard feature for regular expressions. According to [this FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html) it should be supported by all `sed` implementations.

> Groups can also be nested `\(like \(this\) is here\)` and may contain
>   any valid RE. Backreferences repeat the contents of a particular
>   group, using a backslash and a digit (1-9) for each corresponding
>   group. In other words, `/\(pom\)\1/` is another way of writing
>   `/pompom/`.